# L preview JobScheduler API doesn't work correct

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying to run L preview SDK example for JobScheduler API, but it doesn't run as Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE which is used to create an instance of JobScheduler is not recognized.
I checked Context documentation also for API 20(as it doesn't allow to change to 21), but even there no documentation on JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE.

Along with that JobService interface doesn't have many of the callback methods like onCreate(),onDestroy(), onStartCommand(),onStartJob() which are used to write this sample in L SDK.

This is the message that I get when I hover over these methods inside the sample. 
This method is not overriding anything with the current build target, but will in API level 21.

I have double checked for the API level mentioned in the sample and it's 21.

Comment: "I checked Context documentation also for API 20(as it doesn't allow to change to 21), but even there no documentation on JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE." -- the L JavaDocs are here: http://developer.android.com/preview/reference.html

Answer (score 1):

i observed that tragetsdk should be `L`, like `android:targetSdkVersion="L"`. this worked for me. i  also able run a sample job scheduler application.